# CIDetector: CIFaceFeature with always zero bounds

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I have no idea why CIFaceFeature I get always returns zero Rectangle:

```
import Cocoa
import QuartzCore

let url = NSURL(string:"http://cs620522.vk.me/v620522149/12b59/ijvZ6XJWrw0.jpg");
let ciimg:CIImage = CIImage(contentsOfURL:url);
let cid:CIDetector = CIDetector(ofType:CIDetectorTypeFace, context:nil, options:[CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]);
let results:NSArray = cid.featuresInImage(ciimg, options: NSDictionary());
for r in results {
    let face:CIFaceFeature = r as CIFaceFeature;
    NSLog("Face found at (%f,%f) of dimensions %fx%f", face.bounds.origin.x, face.bounds.origin.y, face.bounds.width, face.bounds.height);
}
```

[image]

According to amount of NSLogs it seems CIDetector.featuresInImage works.

Comment: Can you put your code in your question as actual text, instead of an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `println` to log the info. Or you can use the following,

```
NSLog("%@ face", face.bounds.origin.x.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few questions the might inform an answer:

- Is the call to CIImage(contentsOfURL:url) resulting in a valid image?
  For example, is the resulting image extent a non empty rect?
- Does the image have orientation metadata?